# Unable to write dataframe into Hive partitioned parquet table using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am trying to write my data frame into Partitioned hive table .Hive table format is parquet .

But i am unable to write the df to Hive table.

I am trying to write my data frame into Partitioned hive table .Hive table format is parquet .

But i am unable to write the df to Hive table.

Spark2.3 and Partitioned hive table

When i tried to load my finaldf into hive partitioned table i getting the below error

```
finaldf.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").partitionBy("mis_dt","country_codfe").saveAsTable("FinalTable")
```

Error : u'Cannot overwrite table schema.Offertablethat is also being read from;'

When i google for the above error they have sugessted to load df into temp table and load into final hive table . I tried that option and again it failed with different error .

```
finaldf.createOrReplaceTempView('tmpTable') 
final= spark.read.table('tmpTable') 
final.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("Finaltable")
```

Error : Number of partitions created is 7004 which is more than 1000 .

But i do not think that we have that many partitions .

finaldf.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").partitionBy("mis_dt","country_codfe").saveAsTable("FinalTable")

2nd option :

```
finaldf.createOrReplaceTempView('tmpTable')
final= spark.read.table('tmpTable') 
final.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("Finaltable")
```

I am looking to write the data into hive parquet file format table using spark 2.3

```
finaldf.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").partitionBy("mis_dt","cntry_cde").saveAsTable("finaltable")
```

Answer (score 0):

`spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode` is introduced in Spark >= 2.3

```
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")    
sparkConf.set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
sparkConf.set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
```

Use below code -

```
final.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto("table")
```

Note: The table should be created in Hive with partition.

Comment: Thank you .  https://stackoverflow.com/users/3715328/kishore  but at the end i am getting the below error as below pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Number of dynamic partitions created is 7004, which is more than 1000. To solve this try to set hive.exec.max.dhttps://stackoverflow.com/users/3715328/kishoreynamic.partitions to at least 7004.;

Comment: you can't set partition no in spark. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19881